# Knockout-IE not Sorting Observable Array (Chrome and Firefox does)

Tags: knockout.js, single-page-application, knockout-2.0, hottowel

I am working on a Single Page Application with knockout.
I have been banging my head against the wall for this very strange problem. IE has strangely decided not to Sort my observable arrays, whereas Chrome and Firefox do work as expected.

Here's the code: The tr click event calls the sort function but IE simply doesn't sort it

```
var lastResponseSort = '';

var sortResponses = function (data, event) {
var sortField = $(event.target).attr("data-arg");

   if (sortField !== undefined) {
   var descending = lastResponseSort != "";
   lastResponseSort == "" ? lastResponseSort = sortField : lastResponseSort = "";

   // Sort Array here
   arrResponses.sort(function (x, y) {
      if (descending) {
      return x[sortField] > y[sortField] ? -1 : 1;
      } else {
       return x[sortField] < y[sortField] ? -1 : 1;
      }
    });
   }
```

HTML:

```
   <table id="crisis-info">
   <thead>
     <tr data-bind="click: sortResponses">
        <th data-arg="eventName">Response name</th>
        <th data-arg="eventRelatesCrisisTypes()[0].crisisType().name">Crisis Type</th>
        <th data-arg="numberOfPeopleAffected">Affected</th>
        <th data-arg="country().name">Country &amp; Region</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody data-bind="visible: arrResponses().length > 0, foreach: arrResponses">
       <tr>
        <td><span data-bind="text: eventName(), attr: { title:eventName() }"></span>
        </td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: eventRelatesCrisisTypes()[0].crisisType().name(),attr: { title: eventRelatesCrisisTypes()[0].crisisType().name() }"></span>
        </td>
        <td align="center"><span data-bind="text: numberOfPeopleAffected()"></span>
        </td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: country().name() + ',  ' + country().region().name()"></span></td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
```

The part of the problem which is more fascinating is that on applying debugger and going through the sort function, IE is not even sorting the array, let alone updating UI which I thought was the problem, and not throwing any error also. If anyone has faced this problem or knows the workaround, please share it.
Thanks

Comment: `x[sortField]` is not what you want. You'll need to do something like `eval('x.' + sortField)`.

Comment: Still the same...works well with chrome but doesnt in IE :(

Comment: Since the properties are observables, you need to unwrap them too: `eval('x.' + sortField)()`. As I see it, there's no way your code could work in any browser.

Comment: You are right...on observing carefully, Chrome and Firefox were also sorting data randomly..This works like charm...please answer it so that I can accept it...Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're trying to dynamically access properties and/or subproperties of your objects, you'll need to use `eval` instead of dynamic property access. Thus `x[sortField]` will need to be `eval('x.' + sortField)`.

Also because the properties are observables, you'll need to add trailing parentheses too: `eval('x.' + sortField)()`.

Here is your updated sort function (with some other optimizations):

```
arrResponses.sort(function (x, y) {
    var xLess = eval('x.' + sortField + '() < y.' + sortField + '()');
    if (descending) {
        return xLess ? 1 : -1;
    } else {
        return xLess ? -1 : 1;
    }
});
```

Another solution, one that I'd recommend more strongly, is to use computed observables in your objects to encapsulate the displayed data. Thus your `Response` object would contain the following:

```
this.crisisType = ko.computed(function () {
    return this.eventRelatesCrisisTypes()[0].crisisType().name();    
}, this);

this.countryRegion = ko.computed(function () {
    return this.country().name() + ', ' + this.country().region().name();
}, this);
```

Now you could bind to these computed observables in your view and use them in your sort function without having to use `eval`.